# String of "1000" and I need to display it as "10.00"/10.00 (string or number)-- ES6 Solution?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a string of "1000"

I need to display it as 10.00 (either as a string or a number)?

Do you have an ES6 Solution?

Again, I need to display "1000" as either 10.00 or "10.00"

not 1000.00 or "1000.00"

Comment: Why not just `var x = "10.00"`?

Comment: `(Number("1000") / 100).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, it will be a variable value from the DB, not hard coded. That was just an example for clarity.

Comment: Not sure why this question was put on hold. It seems multiple users understood exactly what the problem was without any additional details needed. I received the answer I needed quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm totally stealing this from [@Xufox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/xufox), but I was testing [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908098/string-of-1000-and-i-need-to-display-it-as-10-00-10-00-string-or-number#comment67101385_39908098) for myself anyway, and he doesn't seem to bother to post an official answer, so I'll just share my proof-of-concept here:

[`(Number("1000")/100).toFixed(2)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) will do the trick.

```js
$("#input").on("input",function(){
  $("#output").val((Number($(this).val())/100).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input" /> input<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="output" disabled="disabled" /> output
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5kgcfL87/**

Comment: Nice work. You can omit the `Number()` call, because `/` will do that implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input will always be a string representing an integer, you can just do a simple string replace operation to insert a `.` at the appropriate spot:

```
input.replace(/\d\d$/,".$&")
```

If you want to allow for inputs of only one digit, e.g., `"1"` -> `".01"` then maybe something like this:

```js
let insertDot = s => s.length === 1 ? ".0" + s : s.replace(/\d\d$/,".$&");

console.log(insertDot("1000"));
console.log(insertDot("12345"));
console.log(insertDot("19"));    
console.log(insertDot("9"));
```

(`let` and `=>` used to satisfy your requirement for an ES6 solution...)